# "nurnoch" or "nur noch"?

Tags: single-word-request

Does there exist an actual word "nurnoch", or is it supposed to be the two words "nur" and "noch" after each other? Sometimes I have seen "nurnoch" in writing but I doubt how valid it is.

Comment: Online Duden doesn't know "nurnoch" and links to "Hornochs"  - I hope this is not supposed to be a hint ;).

Comment: @tofro True, but on the other hand google ngram viewer shows some occurances in German books.

Comment: @IngoBochmann: if you click on search results from Google books you will find that most (but not all I admit) of the occurrences do have a blank between *nur* and *noch*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Nur noch* is and has always been written separately. If you find it written together it is an OCR scanning error (as in Google search results), a typing error, or a spelling mistake.

Examples from 16. Century until today:

> Mecklenburg-Vorpommern und Sachsen-Anhalt haben bereits angekündigt, dass Eltern künftig **nur noch** für das älteste Kind Beiträge bezahlen sollen. <sup>[Die Zeit 13.12.2018](https://www.zeit.de/gesellschaft/familie/2018-09/kindertagesstaetten-gute-kita-gesetz-franziska-giffey-kinderbetreuung)</sup>
>
> Das selige Land leidet **nur noch** von einer Bezauberung, indem es dem Wechsel der Jahreszeiten unterworfen ist, Heinrich zerstört das Sonnenreich. <sup>Novalis: Heinrich von Ofterdingen: Ein nachgelassener Roman, 1802</sup>
>
> Und er sprach / Ah zürne nicht Herr / das ich **nur noch** ein mal rede / Man möchte vieleicht zehen drinnen finden. Er aber sprach / Jch wil sie nicht verderben / umb der zehen willen <sup>1.Mose 18,32 Martin Luther 1545</sup>

[image]
<sup>[Postilla Catholica Evangeliorum de Tempore totius Anni. Calenius, 1577](https://books.google.de/books?id=RfRVAAAAcAAJ&dq=%22nur%20noch%22&pg=PA353#v=onepage&q=%22nur%20noch%22&f=false)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Here is what authoritative reference books say:

1) Duden Univeralwörterbuch A-Z, 2. ed. 1989 (i.e. pre-reform) has no lemma *nurnoch*, but discusses the meaning of *nur noch* in the pretty lengthy and detailed lemma of *nur*.

2) Duden Deutsches Universalwörterbuch 8th ed. 2015 (post-reform), Page 1280, does it practically the same way (with less detail).

Conclusion: recommended writing is in two separate words.

Interestingly, *nurmehr* (which can have the same meaning as *nur noch*, but sounds a bit old-fashioned) is listed with a lemma of its own with both spellings mentioned equally, i.e. *nur mehr* and *nurmehr*. - Duden Universalwörterbuch of 2015 attributes *nurmehr / nur mehr* (as alternative for *nur noch*) especially to Austrian German.

Comment: *»nurmehr (which ... sounds a bit old-fashioned)«* In Austria *»nur mehr«* doesn't have an old-fashioned sound, but *»nur noch«* has still a little bit of a *german* sound (*"german"* not in the sense of the language, but of the country), although *nur noch* becomes more and more frequent in Austria, and I think today it is even more frequent than *nur mehr*.

Comment: Just a side note: _nurmehr_ is excessively used by the austrian author Thomas Bernhard.

Comment: Nurnoch ist im Vergleich zu nur noch um 4 10er-Potenzen seltener, und schaut man sich Fälle an, dann findet man offenbare Worttrennprobleme wie "undAbbie Hoffman, befreundet – gibteskeinen Anlass zu glauben, dass die Regierung nurnoch den Ausweg sah,ihnermorden zulassen".

Comment: @userunknown  Es ist immergut, den Dingenauf den Grundzu gehen. Gerade bei Wortstatistiken, die sich auf eingescannte Textestützen.